# Is there any way to use MVVM software architectural pattern in a KMM project without using moko mvvm?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm new to KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile). I need to use MVVM in this project and I just need to use jetpack for ViewModels. So, how can I organize MVVM architecture in the KMM project?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `expect/actual` declaration for your viewmodels, where you can use the architectural `ViewModel`s in your Android actual declarations.

[This example](https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground/blob/master/common/src/androidMain/kotlin/com/halcyonmobile/multiplatformplayground/shared/CoroutineViewModel.kt) does the exact same thing.

The expect/actual documentation you can find [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-connect-to-apis.html)